# Set manual time to today date and make datetime object in ios6

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-simulator, ios6

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";
NSTimeZone *gmt =  [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];
NSString *cur_date= [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"%@",cur_date);
```

Now I am setting the manual time to today's date:

```
NSString *cur_time=@"13:05:08";

dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
NSDate *date_obj=[dateFormatter dateFromString:[cur_date stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@",cur_time]];
NSLog(@"%@",date_obj);
```

but I am getting today date in `NSlog` to show as

```
2012-09-28 07:35:08 +0000
```

even if I set the time as `13:05:08`.

How do I set the manual time to the current date and make one `datetime` object from that?

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";
//You can either use UTC or GMT
NSTimeZone *gmt =  [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"];// This is where I made the change
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];
NSString *cur_date= [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"%@",cur_date);    

NSString *cur_time=@"13:05:08";

dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
NSDate *date_obj=[dateFormatter dateFromString:[cur_date stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@",cur_time]];
NSLog(@"date %@",date_obj);
```

Hope this will work

Comment: I already check this but it still give wrong time in date object

Comment: but when i checked, it gave me this... 2012-09-28 13:05:08 +0000

Answer (score 0):

```
//Try using Time Interval

[myDate addTimeInterval:entertimeinterval];
```